# action if MySQL query is NULL

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is to send visitor to an error page if query is empty or there is a bad code name? My Current Script echos the following "There will be no hacking on this website!", but this is all happening on the same page where original query is sent from.

THe goal is to send visitor to my custom error page that is inside the same folder where the first page is.

```
http://www.example.com/download/file.php 

http://www.example.com/download/error.php
```

and my current script is

```
    <?php
$host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'My_DB_Name';
$db_user = 'MY_User_Name';
$db_pass = '******';
$path_to_file_directory = 'download/files/';
mysql_connect( $host, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db( $db_name ) or die(mysql_error());

$file_code = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'urlid' );

# Query for file info
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Files` WHERE `urlID`='".$file_code."'") or die ( mysql_error() );

# If query is empty, there is a bad code name
# This catches possible hacking attempt.
if( mysql_num_rows($res) == 0 )
{
echo 'There will be no hacking on this website! ';
exit();
} 

# Save file info into an array called "$info"
$info = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 

# File path is below
$file_path = $path_to_file_directory.$info['file_name'];

# Now push the download through the browser
# There is more than 1 way to do this.
if (file_exists($file_path)) {
echo '<p>if it does not: <a href="'.$file_path.'">click here to try again</a>.</p>';
exit;
}

?>
```

I understand that I have to change the echo to something else, but I have no idea what I have to use instead, since simply placing the link to an error page inside echo will only echo it on my file.php page

Please help

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Thank you for you response and suggestion, I am actually trying to learn PHP and already started to do so, but as you can judge by the script in my question, I am only a beginner.

Comment: @Zlatan, Thanks for you response, I have just updated my code to a full version of it

Comment: I belive others have answered it, try redirecting to another page instead of outputing error in the parent page container!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you need is a redirect to another page. You can use the `header` function for it.

```
<?php
if( mysql_num_rows($res) == 0 )
{
  header('Location: /nohacking.php');
  exit();
} 
?>
```

This will redirect your browser to the nohacking.php file.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you haven't sent any headers yet (i.e., basically, this is before any HTML):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0)
{
die(header("Location: error.php"));
}
```

The header() function will redirect the page, and the die() function will stop the rest of the PHP from being processed.

Comment: Thanks for this, do I still have to use or 'die ( mysql_error() );' which I have in my original script, if I am going to go with your option?

Comment: You should for debugging purposes (you may not want to in production code). mysql_error() will only throw an error if something went wrong with the query. This does not include an empty return (which is what mysql_num_rows($res) == 0 is testing for). So yes, keep it if you want your code to stop running completely if the query doesn't work (e.g. if you were trying to search in a column that doesn't exist).